# error: String.format is not accepting event.getActionCommand() [as object]

Tags: java, eclipse, event-handling, actionlistener, string.format

I was just writing a basic `GUI` program in Java using event handler. all code is working fine except a little error at

```
string s = String.format("field 1 is %s", event.getActionCommand())
```

Error is

> the method format(String, object) of type String is not applicable for arguments format(String, String)`'.

So definitely `event.getActionCommand())` is returning a string. But format method is not accepting that.

I was doing this code in eclipse (kepler) using one of the famous tutorial on internet. His code worked but not mine. I am quite a beginner in Java. Please help me in finding this silly error.

Here is my code.

```
package tushar_GUI;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

public class tush extends JFrame{

private JTextField textbox1;
private JTextField textbox2;
private JTextField textbox3 ;
private JPasswordField textbox_pass1;

public tush(){
    super("TITLE");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    textbox1 = new JTextField(10);
    add(textbox1);

    textbox2 = new JTextField("Enter Your Text Here", 30);
    add(textbox2);

    textbox3 = new JTextField("This is UNEDITABLE textbox", 30);
    textbox3.setEditable(false);
    add(textbox3);

    textbox_pass1 = new JPasswordField("password");
    add(textbox_pass1);

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    textbox1.addActionListener(handler);
    textbox2.addActionListener(handler);
    textbox3.addActionListener(handler);
    textbox_pass1.addActionListener(handler);

}

private class thehandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String string = "";

        if(event.getSource() == textbox1)
            string = String.format("field 1 is %s",     event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource() == textbox2)
            string = String.format("field 2 is %s",     event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource() == textbox3)
            string = String.format("field 3 is %s",     event.getActionCommand());
        else if(event.getSource() == textbox_pass1)
            string = String.format("password field is %s",     event.getActionCommand());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
    }
}

}
```

And here my main class

```
package tushar_GUI;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class gui1 {

public static void main (String[] args){

    tush tushObject = new tush();
    tushObject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    tushObject.setSize(500, 500);
    tushObject.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I used this tutorial " http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=31&number=52 "
  tutorial no. 52,53,54

Comment: Run your code no problems...

Comment: I see you posted this a long time ago. Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a action command to your textboxes

solution:

```
textbox1 = new JTextField(10);
textbox1.setActionCommand("textbox1 ");
add(textbox1);

textbox2 = new JTextField("Enter Your Text Here", 30);
textbox2.setActionCommand("textbox2 ");
add(textbox2);

textbox3 = new JTextField("This is UNEDITABLE textbox", 30);
textbox3.setActionCommand("textbox3 ");
textbox3.setEditable(false);
```